# Attempting a sample query in PostgreSQL, but the ROUND function isn't working properly? Issues with my syntax?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working through some online courses and am trying to run some practice queries on my own to calculate 'net sales to inventory' as a percentage in a sample table using the following syntax:

```
SELECT (ROUND((SUM(payment.amount)/SUM(replacement_cost))*100),2) 
  AS nsales2inventory_pct
FROM film
INNER JOIN inventory
ON film.film_id = inventory.film_id
INNER JOIN rental
ON inventory.inventory_id = rental.inventory_id
INNER JOIN payment
ON rental.rental_id = payment.rental_id
WHERE payment.amount > 0.00;
```

I'm getting the correct result which is 21%, but am trying to drill down into a more precise number by using the ROUND function as shown in the SELECT statement above while adding the 2 decimal place requirement into the ROUND function changes the result from 21 in 'numeric' type to '21,2' in a 'record' data format, which I'm unfamiliar with. I'm sure I don't understand what I'm doing wrong because I'm not far enough along yet, but can someone explain to me how I have to adjust the ROUND function when including aggregate/mathematical operators within it?

Comment: Your parentheses are in the wrong place.  Get rid of the one before `ROUND` and the one after `100`.  The way you are doing it now, you create a `record` containing the result of a `round()` to zero decimal places followed by the bare `2`.

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much. I was sitting here for a good half hour trying to figure it out. So placing it into the parenthesis creates record? Can you give me some quick clarification/context about what a record type value is? Is the ',2' that I was getting simply a concatenation of what I was typing at the end of the function?

Comment: A `record` is just a bunch of data elements put together and separated by commas.  Try this:  `select 1, 2;` and then this `select (1, 2);` then this `select pg_typeof((1,2));` to illustrate.  You can also try `select (film) from film;`.  You do not want a `record` here.  You want a single `numeric` result.  Your typo/syntax problem produced a `record` by accident since the second argument to `round()` is optional.  Had it not been for that, then you would have gotten a syntax error for the missing argument.

Answer (score 0):

The `ROUND()` function rounds (to a specific number of decimal places) whatever number you pass to it. It doesn't matter if it's the result of a sum, a simple or complex expression, or just a plain number.

In your case, your first line could look like:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(payment.amount) / SUM(replacement_cost), 2)
```

See these examples that illustrate the rounding:

```
select
  round(21.34567) as r0,
  round(21.34567, 1) as r1,
  round(21.34567, 2) as r2,
  round(21.34567, 3) as r3,
  round(21.34567, 4) as r4
```

Result:

```
r0  r1    r2     r3      r4      
--- ----- ------ ------- ------- 
21  21.3  21.35  21.346  21.3457
```

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing the quotient to be treated as floating point *before* rounding to two decimal places:

```
SELECT ROUND(100.0 * SUM(payment.amount) / SUM(replacement_cost), 2)
       AS nsales2inventory_pct
FROM film
INNER JOIN inventory
...
```

The potential issue I see with your current expression is that Postgres might be treating it as integer division, and therefore discarding the decimal component before you get a chance to round to two decimal places.

Comment: I thought that might be the issue, but even when I switch it over or even take out the factor of 100 altogether, I get the same result. I've tried everything I can reasonably think of and it's still got me scratching my head.

Comment: Before you discard my answer, have you actually tried the _exact_ above code?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by switch it over, sorry if I was unclear. At any rate, Mike helped me resolve it above, it turns out that including the parenthesis around the ROUND function made it create a record of the ROUND result with no decimals, followed by the 2 as a concatenated result.